# why does this IF statement work on the command line but not in a script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

The following works on the command line as root

```
if [[ -e /var/log/apache2/error.log ]]; then echo YES; fi
YES
```

yet this, in a script, does not

```
if [[ -e /var/log/apache2/error.log ]]; then
    echo YES
fi
```

Any idea why this might be? I'm not getting the expected output or an error.

First line of the script is `#!/bin/bash`

As the script is called by a PHP script (www-admin), I thought maybe its due to file permissions, but the error.log file has read permissions

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root adm 1763810 Sep 17 09:02 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Parent folder permissions

```
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4096 Mar 20  2019 var
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 12288 Sep 17 06:25 log
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root       4096 Sep 17 06:25 apache2
```

How the PHP script calls the bash script

```
$cmd = "sh myscript.sh";
$output = array();
$output = shell_exec($cmd);
```

The script runs fine without the IF statement..

Comment: To be completely sure: does "doesn't work" mean that you are getting an error or that it is not printing "YES"? Also, what are the ownership and permissions of the involved directories (`/var`, `/var/log`, `/var/log/apache2`)?

Comment: What's the first line of the script?

Comment: Running the script with `sh` will ignore the `#!`-line in the script itself. See [terdon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/609819/116858)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are calling your bash script with `sh`. This is usually a basic POSIX shell like `dash`. The `[[` isn't POSIX, it's a bashism (also present in some other shells) so your `sh` doesn't support it:

```
$ dash -c "if [[ 10 -gt 8 ]]; then echo yeah; fi"
dash: 1: [[: not found
```

So, either change your script to use the standard `[` (you're not using any special features of `[[` anyway):

```
if [ -e /var/log/apache2/error.log ]; then
    echo YES
fi
```

Or change your PHP script and call the script with bash explicitly:

```
$cmd = "bash myscript.sh";
```

or, since you do have a `#!/bin/bash` shebang, and assuming the script has the executable bit set, just call it directly:

```
$cmd = "./myscript.sh";
```